# How to monitor the D-Link DWS-4026 based wifi network

Tags: ieee-802.11, packet-loss

We have a dws-4026 and 22 access points attached to it, with 9 vlans on every access point. Once in week we have terrible wifi connection in our building, sometimes the rebooting of  the controller switch helps, but there is no strict correlation with anything.
We have about 500 imac spread throughout the building with a wire to each, actually we do not use wifi to connect imacs, and I do not know how to start the troubleshooting, maybe there is a software that can be installed on imacs and report the connection strength and delays to gateways for example?
DWS can export sflow, but I can not find a reason to prove that it shout be exported somewhere to help this situation.

Update:
Probably our neighbors from the upper floor forceing their aironets to transmit at maximal power or something like that.

Comment: A good rule of thumb in troubleshooting is to start with layer-1 and work your way up. In this case, layer-1 is the airwaves. You need a complete wireless site survey to determine outside interference.

Comment: any point where I can start? A book, an article, please.

Comment: Product and resource recommendations are off-topic for this forum.

Comment: Have you looked at the controller's monitoring features?  Logs?  What does it report when things are "terrible?"

Comment: First I thought that enabling sflow can help, but checking the physical layer first sounds reasonable. Nothing in logs.